# Hosts file resetting on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file, reset

Recently I've noticed my hosts file resetting itself.

```
 D:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc  (OS installed on D drive)
```

First time it reset it to the default, and now for the first time its completely disappeared after installing a whole bunch of updates.

I don't have any virus protection other than Microsoft's Security Essentials.

What's going on???

Comment: i would assume a virus would ADD entries rather than delete them anyway! unless its virus protection removing the changes - in which case i'd only expect it to remove entries for rogue entries for popular sites such as facebook.com

Comment: if anyone else upvotes this question - could you please comment if that means you have the same problem. i'm wondering if its due to a recent update or something else

Comment: +1 I have the same problem.  I would like to know if there is a way to mark the current version as correct (I have intentionally added "rogue" entries for facebook.com to block the "Like" button and I want these to be preserved.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google shows that MSE does in fact play around with your hosts file:[link](http://blogs.computerworld.com/14971/testing_microsoft_security_essentials_and_the_hosts_file)

Maybe try disabling/uninstalling it and see if it persists.